# What is the name of this medical practice?

Tags: practice-of-medicine

new here. I am a software engineer and I want to make a thesis about medical practices with virtual mannequins using Virtual Reality.

What I've seen so far is that they use tubes to put down trough the throat and touches the mannequin in certain areas for pain detection or for reanimation practice.

I have 0 experience with medical procedures, standards, rules and tools. To start with I would like to know the name of the practice that doctors and students do with simulated or real patients.

PD. I really don't know which tags should I use, please help me.

[image: medical practice, photo by Fox News https://www.foxnews.com/health/michigan-nursing-school-uses-mannequins-for-medical-lessons]
Photo source: [Fox News](https://www.foxnews.com/health/michigan-nursing-school-uses-mannequins-for-medical-lessons)

Comment: What do you mean by the "name of the practice?" Mannequins of various sorts have been used in different aspects of medical training for many years. There really isn't a name for this that I know of. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry about that, for example if doctors are making a heart surgery to a patient, then it is called Cardiac surgery correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct, but how does that relate to your question?

Comment: I don't know the name of the action/practice doctors do when putting a tube in the patient's throat and supply oxygen. Or if it is just a career subject which I also don't know the name

Comment: Intubation is the name for putting a tube in the patient's throat (specifically, into the trachea). Why did you include a photo of something completely different? Why did you mention other procedures that use a mannequin?

Comment: Mannequins used in medicine are called _manikins_; also artificial patients, dummies or dolls.... They are used for teaching/learning process and the practice of using them may not have a general name. So, you need to know a name of a specific real (live) procedure and then you can say that someone learns this procedure using a manikin. Examples are manikins to learn anatomy, artificial breathing and heart massage, immobilization, oropharyngeal intubation, gastric aspiration, endoscopy, surgery procedures, dealing with a patient in the bed (in your picture) and so on.

Comment: Here's a huge [A-Z list of medical procedures](https://www.medicinenet.com/procedures_and_tests/alpha_a.htm). You can then use a search engine and combine the names of these procedures with "manikin."

Comment: In our practice we use "Bate's guide to physical examination and history taking" as our bible in examining patients.

Answer (score 4):

There is a site called [Anatomy Stuff](https://www.anatomystuff.co.uk/) which specialize in providing replications of the human body.

In particular, they have a section called [Anatomy Models](https://www.anatomystuff.co.uk/anatomical-models.html), which has a range of human-esque models, but these are a bit obsolete these days!

[Clincal Skills Training](https://www.anatomystuff.co.uk/clinical-skills-training-models.html), another of their sections, has life-like human *manikins* that can be used to mimic real people.